# ADB suddenly not responding in Android Studio

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

I'm using Android Studio 1.3.2 and without warning my AVD Emulator stopped working. I then tried my own device but when running Debug I get the following message

```
Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse
Restart ADB integration and try again
```

I've restarted ADB several times and also used Killall ADB from the command line. I've then ran all my updates and reset Android Studio but nothing seems to make ADB respond. Can someone please suggest how I can get my emulator and ADB working again?

Comment: close all applications....open Task manager and check how many adb instances are running...and close them all...then check

Comment: I suppose you already did a system restart?

Comment: I answered it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011793/my-application-cant-start-debug-mode-in-android-stduio I was the one with a mac, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Start Task Manger.

2.) Go to Processes tab.

3.) Find adb.exe

4.) Select adb.exe and click on End Process.

This will solve the problem.