# My Application can't start debug mode in Android Stduio

Tags: android

The logcat show:

```
 Waiting for device.
Target device: lge-nexus_4-01aa55d2b923e7a9
```

Uploading file local path:

```
C:\Users\HOXCN\AndroidStudioProjects\Horcrux\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.hoxcn.horcrux
No apk changes detected.
Skipping file upload, force stopping package instead.
```

DEVICE SHELL COMMAND:

```
am force-stop com.hoxcn.horcrux
```

Launching

```
application:com.hoxcn.horcrux/com.hoxcn.horcrux.ui.activity.SplashActivity.
```

DEVICE SHELL COMMAND:

```
am start -D -n  
com.hoxcn.horcrux/com.hoxcn.horcrux.ui.activity.SplashActivity" -a 
android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN   
cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
cmp=com.hoxcn.horcrux/.ui.activity.SplashActivity }
```

Warning:

```
debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse
```

Restart `ADB` integration and try again(PS: I restart the adb with adb kill-server, don't work)

Waiting for process: `com.hoxcn.horcrux`

If i create a application with a default, the debug mode can run.

If i click run 'app', it work; if i click debug 'app', it show the message above and the screen show the dialog "Waiting for debugger" all the time

Answer (score 1):

You hava to remove ***android:debuggable="true"***, because when you run/debug an application in Android Studio is signed with a debug certificate so that setting is not mandatory.Then check from console if the device is correctly attached with an adb devices. You should see it listed.
**Below steps follow:**

1. **close Android Studio** and any other IDE you have opened (maybe you have Eclipse also running?) and emulator instances;
2. **Remove USB cable from PC**;

3 . Run **adb kill-server** from console;

4 .**Open** Android Studio;

5 . **Click** on run/debug;

6 . when the window to select the device appears, attach your device to USB and USB to your computer;
[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html)

Comment: adb kill-server
* server not running *

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this has happened to me. This usually occurs if you already have an `apk with the same package name but different signature installed in your device`. So the way to fix this is to uninstalll any existing apk's in your device.

Now in some android phones there are options for multiple user accounts and as such if an app is uninstalled it sometimes remains there for the other users. So you should go to the app options in the settings and scroll down to the very bottom. It might show your app at the bottom. Uninstall it from there too and it would work.

Comment: To be more accurate, it's due to existence of apk with same package name **but** different signature.

Comment: If i click run 'app', it work correct; if i click debug 'app', it show the message above

Comment: @nlulin, ok that is something new, I'll see if I find an answer to that !!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Debug icon on the toolbar. It is located right next to the Run icon. Try to launch the app with that.

There is also a debug flag in the AndroidManifest.xml file. It is located under the application tag, and should be set to "true", as follows:

```
<application android:debuggable="true"> </application>
```

OR

Go to Tools => Android => disable adb integration and again enable it
after, Unplugged USB from device and again plugged in. Then press shift + F9

Answer (score 0):

on Mac, I had the same problem.
I had an application to transfer files from my android device, this application causing the problem. All I had to do was to uninstall the androidFileTransfer application and install it again.
Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

You can try to  Restart your android studio and Reconnect your device..Its worked for me

Thank you